# Problems with my compact framework SqlCeException

Tags: exception, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-ce, compact-framework

I have a version problem.

This is the error message I get:

> The application is trying to load native components of version 5386 that are incompatible with ADO.NET provider of version 8080. Incompatible versions can lead to application instability and hence loading of SQL Server Compact has been aborted. Install the correct version of SQL Server Compact. Refer to KB article 974247 for more details.

What have I done:

- I installed and reinstalled and reinstalled every possible SQL Server Compact sp1/sp2, I only find .net compact framework sp1 so that's what I am using

I already had this problem before and was able to solve it with some luck. But now it's worse. These are the programs I installed - maybe I need another installation?

[image: Programs installed]

I'm running on Windows Vista

Comment: If you give up on SQLCE, I suggest SQLite instead.  Even Microsoft started recommending SQLite for new development ( http://www.embedded101.com/Blogs/PaoloPatierno/entryid/387/sqlite-net-compact-framework-39-and-windows-embedded-compact-2013-support )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled visual studio and everything works, possible that I messed up with some extra downloads, so delete everything from the visual studio programs and reinstall it. It was a long way trying to fix this!